# How is this mashed onion paste called?

Tags: oil, onions, blender

I usually make vinaigrette by adding  typical ingredients (garlic, a mix of olive and oil, etc.) and mixing all that together with a blender.

I once added (I am not sure why anymore) some onions to the mix and after blending I got some kind of thick paste. I do not remember the taste anymore but it was probably not extraordinary.

I am curious if such a paste of blended onion and oil (and garlic, spices, ...) is actually used for something useful in cooking?

Comment: It sounds like the first step in a lot of Indian cookery… though I'm not sure how to make an answer out of that snippet of information. The paste itself is called, generically… a purée.

Comment: Was it just garlic, onion, and oil pureed in the blender? The garlic + oil actually makes an *aioli* with the garlic acting as an emulsifier. Adding onion to the mix, I'd probably classify garlic+oil+onion as an *onion aioli*... Though I agree with @Tetsujin that if it's just the onion (or onion + oil), then it's probably just a puree.